# Write and then read at the same time from LocalStorage in ReactJS + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, persistent-storage

I am trying to write to localStorage and then read from localStorage authentication token to access an API.

```
export const authLogin = (username, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    axios
      .post(" http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const token = res.data.key;
        const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
        try {
          localStorage.setItem("token", token);
          localStorage.setItem("expirationDate", expirationDate);
          dispatch(authSuccess(token));
          dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("error storing data");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(authFail(err));
      });
  };
};
```

and then from a ReactJS method i want to read from the localStorage:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { endpoint } from "./constants";
var token = localStorage.getItem("token");

export const authAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: endpoint,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${token ? localStorage.getItem("token") : null}`,
  },
});

class OrderSummary extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  state = {
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.handelFetchOrder();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  handelFetchOrder = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    authAxios
      .get(orderSummaryURL)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          this.setState({
            error: "You currently do not have any order",
            loading: false,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
        }
      });
  };
```

my problem is when i **read** from localStorage. It the token goes null. Which results a 401 api code since we can't read the token to pass it to the api for results. However, if i refresh the web browser (F5) then all goes to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are setting token for your axios when your files load. That means only when the app loads, not after your login. So that item in `localStorage` is null at that time.

So the solution is to setup interceptor for axios instead of your instance of `authAxios`:

```js
const App = (props) => {

  // This will trigger when only once when page refreshes
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        config.headers = {
          ...config.headers,
          Authorization: `Token ${token ? localStorage.getItem("token") : null}`
        };

        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        props.dispatchRedirectToLoginPage()
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }, [])

  return <div>Your app</div>
}
```

So that every request executes this function and it will take token from localStorage.

And every api call that you make make it with `axios.get(...)` or what ever method you need.

Comment: Thanks @Mario Petrovic, I am just wondering what do you mean by isAuthTokenCall?

Comment: thank you. I have actually embedded a method in the authentication action in the Store and every time i log in or signup i make sure the token is used for any api call.

Comment: Nice, i am glad i helped

Comment: And sorry of that `isAuthTokenCall` that is something from my code that i left out

Comment: i am having a problem when i refresh the website , somehow the interceptor dose not work. Where do you think the interceptor should be setup?

Comment: You should set it up in useEffect in main component App probably in your case. I will edit my answer with implementation and you can use components methods to act if there is 401 or any other error

Comment: As  @MarioPetrovic said, using useEffect may solve the issue. It did in my case